# how to join two strings to create a variable name

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, concatenation

there is an array like this in bash

```
array_1=(1 2 3 4 5)
array_2=(6 7 8  9 0)
```

I have another variable that contains 1 or 2 .

```
array_index=1
```

So is it possible to create the array name using that variable - like this ?

```
array_${array_index}[0]
```

Comment: In general, when you think about doing this sort of thing, stop and reconsider. I've never seen a time when dynamically generating a variable name make more sense than putting what you _would_ reference as separate variables into a list/array/collection/container. So use more arrays instead - in your case, an array of arrays.

Comment: @MattBall: in principle, I agree. But bash doesn't have arrays of arrays. Or two-dimensional arrays. It does have string-indexed associative arrays, so you can concatenate two keys with a comma or some such between them in order to fake a two-dimensional array, but that might not be an obvious strategy.

Comment: (Typo: concatenate,  in case anyone else is tired enough that it took more than a moment to figure out. Time for me to sack out, clearly.)

Comment: @MattBall bash makes you do some crazy things! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use variable indirection to read and `declare` to write:

```
array_1=(1 2 3 4 5)
array_2=(6 7 8 9 0)
array_index=1
var="array_${array_index}[0]"

echo "The contents of $var is ${!var}"
declare "$var"="Something Else"
echo "Now $var contains ${!var} instead."
```

This is safer and easier to use correctly than `eval`.

Comment: `declare $var="New Value"` is a little more straightforward than using `printf` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is to access a particular element you have to do something like `${array[index]}`. But you are also wanting to nest a variable in the `array` part , which [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) won't understand when trying to perform the expansion since it expects `array` to be a variable.

So the only way I can think of doing this would be to force the array expansion to happen later than your variables. e.g.

```
> array_1=(1 2 3 4 5)
> array_2=(6 7 8  9 0)
> array_index=1
> eval "echo \${array_$array_index[0]}"
1
```

As `n.m.` points out in comments, [eval](/questions/tagged/eval) is *evil*, so you should [take care](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) when using it.

Comment: @Agreed in general. But depending on how OP is making the arrays it can be fine, and I don't think there is a good way to get around it here.

Answer (score 0):

To create [array](/questions/tagged/array) in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), exactly to set array's value, you can use [eval](/questions/tagged/eval) function, in order to make `${array_index}` statement as a real index, so do as follows:

```
eval array_${array_index}[0]=1
```

To read value, also [eval](/questions/tagged/eval):

```
eval echo \${array_${array_index}[0]}
1
```